# Read "payload" data on NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, payload

I’m using the following code to “read” an nfc tag:

```
@Override
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume();

    // read nfc tag....this is what will "read" the external record?
    if (getIntent().hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {

        NdefMessage ndefMessage = this.getNdefMessageFromIntent(getIntent());

        if(ndefMessage.getRecords().length > 0){

            NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefMessage.getRecords()[0];

            String payload = new String(ndefRecord.getPayload());

            Toast.makeText(this, payload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }


    enableForegroundDispatchSystem();

}
```

I’m getting an error, saying that it “cannot resolve method getNdefMessageFromIntent” Is there another method that I should use to “read” the payload on the tag? Not sure how to fix this….Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 4):

You may try the following:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
if (rawMsgs != null) { // NDEF Message available
    NdefMessage msg =(NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
    NdefRecord ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords(); 

    String payload = new String(ndefRecord[0].getPayload());
    Toast.makeText(this, payload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi corvairjo, I've made a little bit of progress with my application, however I've run into another hurdle. I've opened up another question so I could share more of my code. The link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713709/use-nfc-payload-variable-in-if-statement

You've been a big help so far, I thank you in advance for any add'l help on this topic!

Comment: I'm making steady progress....as I'm able to now write to the tag and read it...however, I'm getting some weird "payload" format results. I've posted another question here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758748/nfc-external-record-is-returning-in-wrong-format

As always, thanks for any help...I've been voting you up for you wherever I can.

Comment: Hi @corvairjo, Thanks again for the help, I've made great progress as a result. I'm able now to see the integer value (1 or 2) when I "scan" the tag. However, I'm not able to actually "read" the tag with the app that is designed to execute code based on that written value. I've posted my entire Main Activity code in the following link...and again, thanks for all of your help!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780932/use-nfc-payload-value-in-an-if-statement